# Installing ElementPlus Icons globally on Vue 3

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, element-plus, el-plus

I am currently working on a project with Vue 3 and Element Plus.

As of the moment, the element plus Icons are not showing on my app.
I have installed them with yarn using
`$ yarn add @element-plus/icons`
and I have no idea what to do next.

I have tried importing it on my **main.ts** file.

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import ElementPlus from "element-plus";
import "element-plus/dist/index.css";
import "@element-plus/icons";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).use(ElementPlus).mount("#app");
```

But it is not showing still.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `@element-plus/icons` package contains named exports for each icon found in the [Icon Collection](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/icon.html#icon-collection). For example, to use the `MagicStick` icon, import it by name, and register it as a component. In Vue 3, you can use a `<script setup>` block to locally register the component simply by importing the component:

```html
<script setup>
import { MagicStick } from '@element-plus/icons-vue'
</script>
```

Then use it as a component in your template:

- within `<el-icon>`, which lets you easily specify the icon's size and color as props

  ***Note:** Clicking an icon card from the [Icon Collection UI](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/icon.html#icon-collection) automatically copies boilerplate markup (`<el-icon><magic-stick/><el-icon>`) to your clipboard for easily pasting it into your own file.*

```html
<template>
  <el-icon :size="100">
    <MagicStick />
  </el-icon>
</template>
```

- or standalone, which requires applying your own styles:

```html
<template>
  <MagicStick class="icon" />
</template>

<style scoped>
.icon {
  color: #f00;
  height: 200px;
}
</style>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-element-plus-icons-5yh5vv?file=src%2FApp.vue)